# Is instantaneous velocity the same as instantaneous rate of change?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The equation for instantaneous velocity is the limit as h approaches 0 of `(f(t+h)-f(t))/h` when `t=time`.
The equation for instantaneous rate of change is the limit as h approaches 0 of `(f(a+h)-f(a))/h` when `a=x of a point`.
Say we have a word problem discussing the position function of a ball falling from a cliff. Its position function is`f(x)=16t^2+100`. Using the functions, both the velocity and instantaneous rate of change would be -40ft/sec at point (1 , 1.5). Is there any difference conceptually between the velocity and instantaneous rate of change? Is velocity simply instantaneous rate of change but in terms of time?

Comment: Velocity is the instantaneous rate of change of position. Velocity is one example of the idea of instantaneous rate of change.

Comment: They are the same. It is just that velocity is a concept used in physics, and instanteneous rate of change is something mathematical.

Comment: And one step further, acceleration is the instantaneous rate of change of velocity.